# Loop through object and remove empties

Tags: javascript, object, json-api

I am using a JSON API spec API v1.1. I am making my frontend cater for this, however, I ran into a slight issue when I was trying to send a relationship back.

I am essentially sending the same object back and altering what I need.

This is an example of how I am doing it:

```
{
    ...originalUser,
    attributes: {
        ...originalUser,
        lastName: 'Doe'
    }
}
```

This all works fine, unless the `originalUser` has a relationship which is completely empty. I know I can do `delete originalUser.relationships.relationship` which will delete the property from the object but this could be any relationship and also the relationship can also have relationships as confusing as that sounds.

Because of this I know that I need to recursively go through the object and delete any object that is empty, which I am afraid to say I have no idea how to do it as I would need to recall a method, I have a rough idea and it would be something like...

```
protected removeEmptyRelationships(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).filter((el) => {
        return el.hasOwnProperty('data');
    });
}
```

An example of a request I am able to send

```
{
    id: '1',
    type: 'users',
    attributes: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    },
    relationships: {
        role: {
            data: {
                type: 'roles',
                id: '1'
            }
        },
        group: {
            data: {
                type: 'groups',
                id: '1',
                relationships: {
                    policy: {}
                }
            }
        },
        type: {}
    }
}
```

So in the example, above I would like the `relationships.type` to be removed and also `relationships.group.relationships.policy` would need to be removed. Obviously as stated earlier this would need to be removed programmatically as I wouldn't know what object it is that I need to remove.

Another thing that I would like to look at is if there is no keys inside of the relationships after the empty ones have been removed, then just remove the whole `relationships` object.

Comment: If you have control over the server side of this (which sounds like the case), this would be much more efficiently handled on the server. Just send back the JSON you need rather than JSON you must modify _again_ on the client.

Comment: does remove means removing or do you want to get a new object without the properties?

Comment: @NinaScholz either or would be fine, a new object would work just the same

Comment: How do you end up with having a `relationships` key on a [resource linkage object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage)? (`relationships.group.relationships`) That's not valid accordingly to JSON:API specification regardless of it's value. If you fix that one, you don't have to recursively check objects anymore, which would make any solution for removing empty objects (which is also not valid accordingly to spec) much easier. Did you consider using an existing JSON:API client to not deal with such issues?

Comment: Hi @jelhan if you look at the example here (v1.1) you can see we are including comments, which is a relationship and the comment also has a relationship, it is valid according to v1.1. https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#document-compound-documents

Comment: @tallent123 You are right that JSON API spec supports including nested resources but these compound documents consists of several independent resource objects. You can not put a `relationships` key on [resource identifier object](https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#document-resource-identifier-objects) but must put it on the resource object for the resource referenced by the resource identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very simple working with the `object` as a `string` and using *regular expressions*. 
try:

```js
const obj = {
    id: '1',
    type: 'users',
    attributes: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    },
    relationships: {
        role: {
            data: {
                type: 'roles',
                id: '1'
            }
        },
        group: {
            data: {
                type: 'groups',
                id: '1',
                relationships: {
                    policy: {}
                }
            }
        },
        type: {}
    }
}


const exp = /"\w*":{}/g;
const exp2 = /,}/g;
let strObj = JSON.stringify(obj);

while(exp.test(strObj)) {
    strObj = strObj.replace(exp,'');
}

strObj = strObj.replace(exp2, '}');
console.log(JSON.parse(strObj))
```

Hope this help.

Comment: nice idea, looping avoided

Answer (score 0):

You could remove unwanted properties by checking the nested values and filter this key/value pairs out. Then build a new object.

```js
function clean(object) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
                v = clean(v);
                if (!Object.keys(v).length) return;
            }
            return [k, v];
        })
        .filter(Boolean)
    );
}

var data = { id: '1', type: 'users', attributes: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }, relationships: { role: { data: { type: 'roles', id: '1' } }, group: { data: { type: 'groups', id: '1', relationships: { policy: {} } } }, type: {} } },
    result = clean(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```